# find tags in defined scope using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have using beautifulsoup to extract datas.

I hava such a html file:

```
<div class=a>
<a href='google.com'>a</a>
</div>
<div class=b>
<a href='google.com'>c</a>
<a href='google.com'>d</a>
</div>
```

I want to extract data 'c,d' in ,I don't need data 'a' in

so I do:

```
google_list = soup.findAll('a',href='google.com')
for item in google_list:
    print item.strings
```

it will print a,c,d.
so my problem is how to just print 'c','d' in  without 'a' in

Comment: by the by, findAll is now deprecated-ish, the beautifulsoup devs changed method names to conform to the new Python style guidelines (findAll -> find_all, etc). Of course, they all still work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just select based upon the `div` whose class is `b` and then after that use your original query on *that tag* so that you look for its children:

```
div = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"b"})[0]
items = div.find_all('a', href="google.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

I stopped using Beautiful soup a few years back and prefer the lxml library whose html parser is flexible and also allows xpath queries.

```
html = """<div class=a>
<a href='google.com'>a</a>
</div>
<div class=b>
<a href='google.com'>c</a>
<a href='google.com'>d</a>
</div>
"""
root = lxml.html.fromstring(html).getroottree()
root.xpath("//div[@class='b']/a[@href='google.com']/text()")
# ['c', 'd']
```

This finds all the text from all the anchors which refer to 'google.com' that are inside any div with a class 'b'.